# .Net Core Session Timeout work on local but not work on live

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I put this code in Startup.cs, it works properly on local machine but not on live server.
live keeps timing out every few minutes

```
services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600);
            options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
            options.CookieName = "ASP.NetCoreSession";
            options.CookiePath = "/";
        });
```

Thanks for support

Comment: What implementation of `IDistributedCache` are you using?

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I used in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache